# в toLocaleString нет локализации ru

Tags: javascript, node.js, локализация

следующий код

```
const date = new Date();
const options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('ru-RU', options));
```

Выводит белиберду

```
2020 M10 19, Mon
```

Хотя у других людей все нормально выводит, в чем может быть проблема?
код выполняется в Node.JS

Comment: может браузер не знает такую локаль?

Comment: Стоит добавить информацию, где именно запускается этот код.

Comment: Добавил в описание. Запускал на Node.js

Comment: Если в Node.js, важна версия. До определённой версии по умолчанию Node.js компилировалась с минимальной поддержкой ICU (в том числе локалей). Сравните дефолтную опцию в 14 и 12 версиях: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/intl.html#intl_options_for_building_node_js и https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/intl.html#intl_options_for_building_node_js

Answer (score 0):

Думаю стоит посмотреть на [совместимость](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) с браузерами. Аргументы locales и options

```js
const date = new Date();
const options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('ru-RU', options));
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего локаль не сгенерированна.

Надо отредактировать файл

```
sudo vim /etc/locale.gen
```

Найти и раскомментировать строчку

```
ru_RU.UTF-8
```

Далее запустить генерацию локалей

```
sudo locale-gen
```

Потом русская локаль будет работать правильно и в NodeJS.